# Importing .dmp file into SQL developer: Do I need to import seperately for each table?

Tags: oracle, schema, import, table, oracle-sql-developer

I have a large `.dmp` file which I would like to import into `SQL developer`. This contains all the data I want to import across several `Schemas`.

Do I need to split this up into each separate `table` in order to import it?

I ask as in [this guide](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm) it suggests importing on a table by table basis.

Comment: Large files and sql developer should be a red flag. ,)

Answer (score 1):

This import file is an export done with a tool such as exp73, exp or expdp.

The manner of importing data you are referring to when you have data in an excel sheet with coma separated value, SQL developer will create a large insert statement with the data for you and run it, which will populate a table.

What you want to do is to use oracle import tools such as impdp or imp.

Do you happen to have the export's log ? There might be a file with the same name that finishes with a .log

Here is an example of syntax on how to import specific tables of an Oracle export

```
impdp username/password@oracle_sid tables=table1,table2 directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=dumpfilename.dmp logfile=import_exec_log.log
```

You will want to run the following query to find where your data pump dir location is and place the export in the corresponding folder :

```
 select * from dba_directories where directory_name ='DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```